# Sharepoint List Hyperlink Column - get Alternative Text in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list, with a Hyperlink column allowing us to quick link to our IT Helpdesk system. The hyperlink column allows for the URL and also alternative text to display. This makes the SP List look cleaner as you're just seeing the IT Ticket Nr rather than the full URL, but it's still clickable.

In PowerApps I would like to get that Alternative Text to display in a gallery, but I can only successfully pull through the full hyperlink using ThisItem.'SN Ticket Link', which is the column name.

How do I show the Alternative Text instead please?
Thanks

SharePoint List hyperlink column:
[image: SharePoint List hyperlink column]

PowerApps Result:
[image: PowerApps Result]

PowerApps Code:
[image: PowerApps Code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the alternative text is not returned by the SharePoint connector, so it cannot be displayed in Power Apps (see below). An alternative would be to split that column into two, with one of them containing the URL itself, and a second one with the alternative text (maybe it can be done with a new calculated column in SharePoint, but I don't know if this is possible - this would be a good new question for the SharePoint tag)

To see the response from SharePoint, you can use the [Power Apps Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/monitor-canvasapps), in which you can see the network requests and responses from the app:

[image]

Comment: In fact, it's possible... Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837140/10263175