# How do I submit a SharePoint form, at the same time I want to upsert the description of a hyperlink column of it that I wrote inside a textbox in PA?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

This question is a follow up of [How do I get the display name of a hyperlink that comes from SharePoint in Power Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76836479/how-do-i-get-the-display-name-of-a-hyperlink-that-comes-from-sharepoint-in-power/76837140?noredirect=1#comment135584764_76837140)

Here is the code I used at the *On Start* of the *App*:

```
    Set(AllFavorites; GruposdoOffice365.HttpRequest("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/X/Lists/Y/items?expand=fields"; "GET"; ""));;

    ClearCollect(
        colAllFavorites;
        ForAll(
            Table(AllFavorites.value);
            {
                Title: Text(Value.fields.Title);
                Url1: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref.Url);
                Description1: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref.Description);
                Url2: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref0.Url);
                Description2: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref0.Description);
                Url3: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref1.Url);
                Description3: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref1.Description);
                Url4: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref2.Url);
                Description4: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref2.Description);
                Url5: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref3.Url);
                Description5: Text(Value.fields.Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref3.Description)
            }
        )
    );;
```

I managed to get through a HTTP request on start of the app the descriptions of hyperlink columns to show on a text box. Now I need to save the changes made on the text box at the same time I submit the form. How do I submit a SharePoint form, at the same time I want to upsert the description of a hyperlink column of it that I wrote inside a text box?

I color coded the URLs to their respective links. The highlighted button is the one that submits the data:

[image]

Comment: Use Send an HTTP request action in Power automate flow to update the description of hyperlink: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88540/how-do-i-update-a-hyperlink-field-using-the-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

You can call the Power automate flow from Power Apps to update the description of hyperlink columns.

Inside Power automate flow, you can use the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action to update the description of hyperlink with the help of SharePoint REST APIs.

[image]

**Source**: [How to: Update SharePoint hyperlink field the proper way with alternative text — Power Automate](https://medium.com/@Mr.Automate/update-sharepoint-hyperlink-field-the-proper-way-with-alternative-text-power-automate-logic-apps-f7ba0280b288)

Related thread for syntax reference: [How do I update a Hyperlink field using the REST API?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88540/how-do-i-update-a-hyperlink-field-using-the-rest-api)

Comment: Does this work for both creating or updating an entry?

Comment: Yes, it works. For creating just use `/items` endpoint without If-Match and X-HTTP-Method headers. For update you will need item ID - `/items(<ItemID>)` of existing item and these headers.

Comment: Is it necessary to include the URL?

Comment: Yes, include both URL in description.

Comment: I ran into the following error, since I need to upsert multiple descriptions, it says that there are less arguments than necessary. In my case, I inserted 12 arguments (1 for the list name, 1 for the entry ID, 6 for the URLs and the other 6 for the descriptions), but it says that the expected is 556.

Comment: What error? Can you add screenshot of what you tried and what is the error to your original question?